# Python/Kivy: How to display an image at a specific mip level?

Tags: python, image, opengl, kivy, textures

How to dynamically set the current mip level of the displayed image (or Texture) in Kivy?

I'd like to implement a bias towards sharper mipmapped images, dynamically overriding the current mip level based on custom scaling logic. I'm relatively new to python and glsl, and am having trouble understanding which parts of the source code (if any) could help here.

From Kivy documentation I've got that both [`Texture`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html) and [`Image/CoreImage`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html) objects used for displaying images in Kivy have a [`keep_data`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.keep_data) property, which, *"keeps the image data when the texture is created"* which seems to be an [`ImageData`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.ImageData) object. `ImageData` can have a [`mipmaps`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.ImageData.mipmaps) property that can store *"data for each mipmap"*. It also has [`get_mipmap()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.ImageData.get_mipmap) method which *"gets the mipmap image at a specific level if it exists"* and [`add_mipmap()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.ImageData.add_mipmap) which *"adds an image for a specific mipmap level"*. And, looking at kivy.core.image source code, the ImageData in question seems to be accessible at

```py
Image(source="image.png", keep_data=True, mipmap=True)._coreimage.image._data
```

but it is a single-item list with a few properties such as size and filepath stored in a long string and seemingly nothing else.

If retrieving individual mip levels is not possible from high-level, can this be achieved with underlying OpenGL, with result accessible by Kivy widgets or widget canvas? If so, a simple example for a beginner would be most welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details of this, but it should hopefully be straightforward to look through the kivy code to find out how it's handled. If it's possible in general, I'm fairly optimistic that it won't be too hard with Kivy.

Comment: @inclement I did look through the code before (image.py, [texture,pyx](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/texture.pyx), image-related code in kivy/core), and it at least _seems_ to be doable to me. It's just that I'm relatively new to programming in general (only slightly familiar with GLSL), and am having difficulties understanding everything that is going on in there. I could not find this mipmap issue addressed directly (examples of pulling that data into a Texture). Before this most of the things I've set out for were achievable with more exposed Kivy functionality ^_^'